# Hive Browser Throwing Error

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

I am trying to put some basic query in hive editor in hue browser , but it is returning the following error whereas my Hivecli works fine and able to execute queries. Could someone help me?

Fetching results ran into the following error(s):

> Bad status for request TFetchResultsReq(fetchType=1,
>   operationHandle=TOperationHandle(hasResultSet=True,
>   modifiedRowCount=None, operationType=0,
>   operationId=THandleIdentifier(secret='r\t\x80\xac\x1a\xa0K\xf8\xa4\xa0\x85?\x03!\x88\xa9',
>   guid='\x852\x0c\x87b\x7fJ\xe2\x9f\xee\x00\xc9\xeeo\x06\xbc')),
>   orientation=4, maxRows=-1):
>   TFetchResultsResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=0, errorMessage="Couldn't
>   find log associated with operation handle: OperationHandle
>   [opType=EXECUTE_STATEMENT,
>   getHandleIdentifier()=85320c87-627f-4ae2-9fee-00c9ee6f06bc]",
>   sqlState=None,
>   infoMessages=["*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Couldn't
>   find log associated with operation handle: OperationHandle
>   [opType=EXECUTE_STATEMENT,
>   getHandleIdentifier()=85320c87-627f-4ae2-9fee-00c9ee6f06bc]:24:23",
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager:getOperationLogRowSet:OperationManager.java:229',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:fetchResults:HiveSessionImpl.java:687',
>   'sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14:invoke::-1',
>   'sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl:invoke:DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43',
>   'java.lang.reflect.Method:invoke:Method.java:606',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:78',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:access$000:HiveSessionProxy.java:36',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1:run:HiveSessionProxy.java:63',
>   'java.security.AccessController:doPrivileged:AccessController.java:-2',
>   'javax.security.auth.Subject:doAs:Subject.java:415',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation:doAs:UserGroupInformation.java:1657',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:59',
>   'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19:fetchResults::-1',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService:fetchResults:CLIService.java:454',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService:FetchResults:ThriftCLIService.java:672',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1553',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1538',
>   'org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction:process:ProcessFunction.java:39',
>   'org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor:process:TBaseProcessor.java:39',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor:process:TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56',
>   'org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:run:TThreadPoolServer.java:285',
>   'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor:runWorker:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145',
>   'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker:run:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615',
>   'java.lang.Thread:run:Thread.java:745'], statusCode=3), results=None,
>   hasMoreRows=None)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error could be either due to `HiveServer2` not running or Hue does not have access to `hive_conf_dir`.

Check whether the `HiveServer2` has been started and is running. It uses the port `10000` by default.

```
netstat -ntpl | grep 10000
```

If it is not running, start the `HiveServer2`

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hiveserver2
```

Also check the Hue configuration file `hue.ini`. The `hive_conf_dir` property must be set under `[beeswax]` section. If not set, add this property under `[beeswax]`

`hive_conf_dir=$HIVE_HOME/conf`

Restart `supervisor` after making these changes.